# How to call a json post function after update panel postback?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, json

I have a gridview inside of UpdatePanel. I need to call json function after update panel refreshed.

Here is the example of my code:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
 <asp:GridView ID="GrvHabits" runat="server" BorderWidth="1" ShowHeader="False" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                        CssClass="mGrid" PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr" Width="90%" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt"
                        OnRowDataBound="GrvHabits_DataBound">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:TemplateField>
                                <ItemTemplate>
```

and here is my json function

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load('visualization', '1', { packages: ['corechart'] });

    function drawVisualization() {
        var id = $('#Id').text();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Services/Charts.asmx/Draw",
            data: "{Id: " + id + " }",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {

                var items = response.d;
```

Answer (score 1):

Handle the endrequest event of the page:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383810.aspx

Comment: it would be very helpful if you can post an example

Answer (score 0):

So the solution for my problem very simple.

I have changed function name to function pageLoad() {}.

And it works like a charm :)